# Remove the false operator in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Here I am trying to add a random hexadecimal value every time a name is entered. It’s working but the other empty cells get filled with `false`.

I want to completely delete the false part as it’s causing problems while automation.

I have tried replacing the `false` with an empty string but my automation software still skips those rows.

Please help!
My formula to get hexadecimal values:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(len(A2:A),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(1,16*sign(row(A2:A))),4)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add one more `,` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(1, 16*SIGN(ROW(A2:A))), 4), ))
```

Comment: Basically i use integromat to send the hexa decimal value column
After putting your code also its skipping rows.
But your code does remove the false operator

Comment: Yeah 
So basically what im trying to do is generate hexadecimal numbers once the name field is entered
I use a automation software called integromat which gets the user input and puts in in google sheets
When i use the formula to generate hexadecimal numbers the false operator is occupying that position
Even if we hide the False operator the value is not changing
And integromat skips all the rows which has data and posts only when an entire row is empty
so i want a script to do the same

Comment: @ChiragChinvar not sure how to help you... am not familiar with integromat nor scripting, but entering my suggested formula should rid of all false operators and therefore solve your question. if you experience other errors you can try setting up IFERROR formula to output nothing

Comment: Can you please give the formula for the above using IFERROR operator?

Comment: sure: `=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(1, 16*SIGN(ROW(A2:A))), 4), )), )`